# Regex match only first char

Tags: regex, match, capture

So basicly I have these lines:

```
line1:blabla:etcetc
line2:blabla2:etcetc2
line3:blabla3:etcetc3
```

I need to capture only the first ' : ' . This is my regex now,but it captures all the ' : '

[(:*?)]

Comment: What are you going to do with the first `:`?

Comment: I need to replace it with a \t

Comment: Which language/tool are you using? Is each line a seperate string or are they all contained in one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `[(:*?)]` regex matches 1 symbol that is either a `(`, or `:`, `*`, `?`, or `)` since the outer brackets form a *character class* (or a bracket expression in POSIX regex) where you define characters, or their ranges, that this construct can match, but it will match 1 char that belongs to the set/ranges.

The first `:` can be matched with

```
^([^:]*):
```

And replace with `$1\t`.

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ2oC9/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^:]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `:` with a nregated character class `[^:]` (note we *capture* what we need to keep)
- `:` - a literal `:` (note we *match* what we need to replace)

And the `$1` in the replacement pattern refers to the value captured in Group 1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: Note that depending on the tool/language/method, it might require `^([^:]*):(.*)` -> `$1\t$2`. Or even a `(?m)` modifier if each *line* must be handled (like `(?m)^([^:\n]*):(.*)`).

Comment: Thanks for the informations! $1\t worked fine. I am using emeditor for this

Comment: I have just added an explanation what your regex matches. Basically, it will match the firs character from the set or all of them if global matching is enabled.

Comment: In case anyone needed like I did to match the first one and not what's before for a *split*, which doesn't let you replace, here's what solved it in Java `str.split(":", 2)`. Which gives you 2 strings : what's before the first `:`, and the rest with all the others `:`